# Spring Scheduler in Clustered environment

Tags: java, spring, cluster-computing, scheduler

I am using spring scheduler using @Scheduled annotation to schedule a job that runs a file generation service. The application is deployed on 5 separate nodes of tomcat in clustered environment for load balancing and fail over.  Because of this, service is scheduled 5 times which is never expected.
Is there a way to configure the scheduler to be run only on the current node?

There is an approach that uses database to figure out the current alive node and invoking the scheduler for that particular instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35226261/2751833)

Another approach is to use [quartz scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering)

Since I could not make major changes to the deployed application, is there a simple solution to the issue? Please advise.

Comment: What changes would be ok to make then?

Comment: Did you find any solution on your question? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288810/spring-scheduled-task-running-in-clustered-environment"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Scheduled Task running in clustered environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288810/spring-scheduled-task-running-in-clustered-environment)

Answer (score 8):

You can use [ShedLock](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock) project. You just annotate tasks which should be locked when executed

```
@Scheduled( ... )
@SchedulerLock(name = "scheduledTaskName")
public void scheduledTask() {
   // do something
}
```

Configure Spring and a LockProvider (SQL and Mongo currently supported)

```
@Bean
public TaskScheduler taskScheduler(LockProvider lockProvider) {
   return SpringLockableTaskSchedulerFactory
             .newLockableTaskScheduler(poolSize, lockProvider);
}
```

Comment: Hey, can you please take a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45561558/shedlock-running-multiple-instances-runs-scheduler-tasks-multiple-times

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [dlock](https://github.com/yusufaytas/dlock) to execute a scheduled task only once over multiple nodes. You can simply do something like below.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "30 30 3 * * *")
@TryLock(name = "jobLock", owner = SERVER_NAME, lockFor = THREE_MINUTES)
public void runJobsOnce() {
  List<Job> jobs = jobService.getJobs();
  for(Job job: jobs){
    runJob(job);
  }
}
```

See the [article](https://dzone.com/articles/simple-mutual-exclusion) about using it.