# ShedLock: Running multiple instances runs scheduler tasks multiple times

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I am using `Shedlock` to run my `scheduler` task only once if multiple instances of the service are running.

I followed the [documentation](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock) and this is what I did.

This is the function that needs to run periodically

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "300000")
@SchedulerLock(name = "onlineIngestionTask", lockAtMostFor = 240000, lockAtLeastFor = 240000)
public void pullTasksFromRemote() {
        //Code
}
```

In my config class I have the following beans

```
@Bean
public ScheduledLockConfiguration taskScheduler(LockProvider lockProvider) {
    return ScheduledLockConfigurationBuilder
        .withLockProvider(lockProvider)
        .withPoolSize(10)
        .withDefaultLockAtMostFor(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
        .build();
}



@Bean
public LockProvider lockProvider(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplateLockProvider(dataSource);
}
```

The pom includes

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
    <artifactId>shedlock-spring</artifactId>
    <version>0.14.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
    <artifactId>shedlock-provider-jdbc-template</artifactId>
    <version>0.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I added a table to my db, the one to which jdbc connects.

```
CREATE TABLE shedlock(
    name VARCHAR(64), 
    lock_until TIMESTAMP(3) NULL, 
    locked_at TIMESTAMP(3) NULL, 
    locked_by  VARCHAR(255), 
    PRIMARY KEY (name)
)
```

After this I tried to test the functionality by running tha pp first on port 8080. Then I use `server.port=9000` to run it again on port 9000. But both these instances start running the task. Am I missing something. Is something wrong in the implementation? Can someone give any ideas. Thanks !!

Comment: I don't know Shedlock, so it might be a stupid question but, have you checked if your instances have a different `locked_by` value ?

Comment: @JeremyGrand The instances are both exactly the same. They only run on different ports. :/

Comment: So don't you think they might both consider they got the lock for themselves ?

Comment: @JeremyGrand I feel that the shedlock library code will somehow self detect this and run only one job at a time. because if I need to have instances that are not identical then there are many ways to do it without shedlock.

Comment: That's why I've written I don't know a thing about Shedlock, your sample doesn't let us know how the `locked_by` field is generated and it seems to me that it is the most important. If the Shedlock automatically generates one, ok, but if you need to set a name in a property, that's pretty easy to do and is IMO an acceptable feature for the library. But you should at least check what is inserted in database by each of your instances.

Comment: @JeremyGrand Your comment makes complete sense. The documentation however doesn't tell anything about inserting any data in the table. I assume that shedlock will do that as well. I am not sure what to insert in locked_by even if I do the insert myself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151345/discussion-between-jeremy-grand-and-varunkr).

Comment: I have the same problemn. Have you got the solution?

Comment: @renanlf No I couldn't I used a different approach

Comment: You can consult this https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock#troubleshooting

Comment: is this solved ?

Comment: @ShameeraAnuranga Can't remember. This was long ago. Although I think that I ended up not using Shedlock

Answer (score 3):

[dlock](https://github.com/yusufaytas/dlock) guarantees to have one lock at any time by using database indexes and constraints. You can simply do something like below.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "30 30 3 * * *")
@TryLock(name = "onlineIngestionTask", owner = SERVER_NAME, lockFor = 240000)
public void pullTasksFromRemote() {

}
```

See the [article](https://dzone.com/articles/simple-mutual-exclusion) about using it.

Answer (score 2):

we recently had this issue in prod where we could see multiple runs of shedlock schedulers. if you are using spring boot 2.2.1.RELEASE onwards then use below deps for shedlock

```
<dependency>
<groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
<artifactId>shedlock-spring</artifactId>
<version>4.9.3</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
        <artifactId>shedlock-provider-redis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try with cron expression inside `@scheduled` instead of `fixedDelayString`, below scheduler run every hour.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */1 * * *")
```

Answer (score 0):

Shedlock guarantees only that the given method won't be executed twice within lock constraints (so taking into account method execution time and defaultLockAtMostFor/defaultLockAtLeastFor parameters). By default Spring uses only one thread for scheduled tasks, which (if one job runs much longer than another, or longer than defaultLockAtLeastFor) may cause for second instance to execute given method when lock is already released. Inmy case adding

```
    @Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    private final int POOL_SIZE = 10;

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();

        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(POOL_SIZE);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("scheduled-task-pool-");
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();
        taskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);
    }
}
```

resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

It is a good challenge to implement the lock yourself using java annotations and aop (Aspect oriented) programming.

Not so complicated to do. A kind of:

```
@Around(" @annotation(com.company.MyLock)")
```

Then use the annotation around the scheduler processing method.

Comment: This won't help in cluster (multi-instance) environment