# Scheduler in clustered environment

Tags: spring, scheduler, galera

Our (Spring) application contains several `Schedulers` which become active during the night to change/update some data (from `Database`) in `Batch`.

This is all running fine, the problem is that our application will soon run in a `clustered environment`.

What are the best options to prevent a `scheduler` of `instance A` and `instance B` are doing the same work at the same time?

** **UPDATE** **

Clustered environment is setup as `'active-active'`. 
Each node communicates with it's own database instance. Each database instance will `replicate` data to the other instances. 
DB-instances are not setup as `'master-slave'` but will run in a `Galera cluster` where each instance executes insert-update-delete operations.

So each `scheduler` should run only once on one instance. The other instances should not run the schedulers. So I need to find a way the a Scheduler of one instance runs, the same schedulers of the other instances should not run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Scheduled Task running in clustered environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288810/spring-scheduled-task-running-in-clustered-environment)

Comment: do you have answer?

Comment: I didn't receive any answers after updating my question for more clarification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for completeness: we ended up with persistent `Quartz job scheduling`. 
[This](http://codrspace.com/Khovansa/spring-quartz-with-a-database/) post helped me a lot about persistent `Quartz scheduling` with `Spring`.

Comment: Link is broken :(

Answer (score 1):

You should delegate different tasks to the nodes in your cluster. What work is happening to the database at night?

If the nodes are clustered correctly behind a load balancer, only one should receive the update to write to a database.

You can use `Zookeeper` to manage nodes and set a primary to perform sole scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

You will have code to handle that scheduled event in both clusters. There are two approaches.

1. You can choose to run this event in any one cluster. Then you need to make sure when this cluster is down, You would switch scheduler in other cluster. And similar maintenance issues.
2. You can choose to run such events in both clusters. Difference in implementation such a way that all clusters will poll and any one cluster will successfully run it. You can choose database or jms message for polling/locking.

I prefer second approach - write once.

Answer (score 1):

You're not saying what sort of `Schedulers` you're using.
What you're looking for is persistant scheduling. JEE has support for this, and Quartz has too. Spring out of the box does not, although it integrates quiet nicely with Quartz if you want to.

With persistant schedulers, jobs are added to the database, and triggers are run in a "transaction"(not sure if it's an actual transaction), ensuring that only one scheduler can run the trigger.
It requires some database tables for management, however.