# How Schedule Quartz Jobs behind an AWS load balancer

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler

I have identical instances running REST Application behind AWS load balancer. I have created a cron Job (QUARTZ) to run 1 hour. The problem is the application on both instances is the same and that means it triggers jobs every hour. How can I listen to the instances and probably know if there is an already triggered Job, so that I do not trigger a new Job doing the same on another instance.

Comment: Maintain State of your job in table & based on flag don't let other job to run the already executed job https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288810/spring-scheduled-task-running-in-clustered-environment/35226261#35226261