# Spring scheduler running twice

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jboss, scheduled-tasks

I deployed the application in **JBoss with master and slave** due to which my scheduler running twice. **ShedLock** is not solution for my problem as the email will triger till user deactivate the expired Asset. So I though of checking the request is from master or slave and based on it I will run my code, any idea how to figure it or any other solution. Thank you
I am using Spring 4.x and REST web-service with MySQL db.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${scheduler.i18n.crontime}")
public void getAssetNotification() {
    try {
        notificationDao.getAssetNotification(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("getAssetNotification() - error in getAssetNotification", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: we are adding the parameter in host file of master and slave server, if it's read from master we will trigger else will not trigger the notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do a synchronization over database?

I found an older code snippet using an aspect:

[Spring Scheduled Task running in clustered environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288810/spring-scheduled-task-running-in-clustered-environment/35911772)

Comment: it's a single database