# Issue about Distributed lock by using ShedLock to have ThreadPoolTaskScheduler process multiple schedule tasks

Tags: spring-boot, shedlock

I know ShedLock could be used to do distributed lock integrated with Spring as:

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * * ?")
    @SchedulerLock(name = "exampleLock", lockAtLeastForString = "20000", lockAtMostForString = "30000")
    private void exampleMethod(){
         System.out.println(String.format("[%s] test job runs...", new Date()));
}
```

But for my case I'd like to execute multiple schedule tasks(Crons) read from Database and process by ThreadPoolTaskScheduler separately and independently. I coded as below, however it doesn't work dealing with multiple instances to execute each scheduled task. Is there any way with Spring or without to achieve this? Any thought will be highly appreciated.

```
public class ExampleShedLock implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Resource
    private ScheduleTaskRepository scheduleTaskRepository;

    @Resource
    private TaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler;

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {

        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(getThreadPoolTaskScheduler());
        Map<String, String> dataMap = scheduleTaskRepository
                .selectExpressionByIsActive();
        dataMap.forEach(
                (key, expression) -> scheduledTaskRegistrar.getScheduler()
                        .schedule(() -> scheduledTask(),
                                (TriggerContext triggerContext) -> {
                                    CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger(
                                            expression,
                                            TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
                                    return trigger.nextExecutionTime(triggerContext);
                                }));
    }

    @SchedulerLock(name = "TaskScheduler",
            lockAtLeastFor = 20*1000, lockAtMostFor = 30*1000)
    private void scheduledTask() {

        System.out.println(
                Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - " + Calendar
                        .getInstance()
                        .getTime();

    }


    @Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskScheduler")
    public TaskScheduler getThreadPoolTaskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.setPoolSize(10);
        taskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("Scheduled-");
        taskScheduler.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new 
        ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        taskScheduler.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        taskScheduler.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(60);
        taskScheduler.initialize();
        return taskScheduler;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure out one way to accomplish the query. Rather than to use @SchedulerLock annotation, I could wrap the TaskScheduler to LockableTaskScheduler with your customized LockConfigurationExtractor and schedule each taskScheduler manually like this:

```
DefaultLockManager defaultLockManager = new DefaultLockManager(lockProvider,
            customizedLockConfigurationExtractor);
return new LockableTaskScheduler(taskScheduler, defaultLockManager);
```

Comment: Could you please update workable solution here or Explain the components written in above solution

Comment: Could you share your fully detailed solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a LockableTaskScheduler object and set this to ScheduledTaskRegistrar. This will check for the shedlock table before each execution.

```
public LockableTaskScheduler getScheduler() {
    LockConfigurationExtractor lockConfigurationExtractor = (task) ->  Optional.
                of(new LockConfiguration(Instant.now(), "schedulerJob", Duration.ofMinutes(15), Duration.ofMinutes(5)));
        
        LockManager lockManager = new DefaultLockManager(lockProvider, lockConfigurationExtractor);
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("MyThreadPoolTaskScheduler");
        scheduler.initialize();
       return new LockableTaskScheduler(scheduler, lockManager);
}
```