# How to avoid duplication of scheduler tasks when deployed in multiple instances

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks

Have a spring Boot application through which i am able to create a cron and schedule the tasks . However when the multiple instances of the app are deployed , the cron gets triggered in all the instances and results in duplication. Is there any configuration which needs to be done in spring level?

We are using redis and using a flag this can be controlled in other instances  but need a better approach for resolving this issue. Tried even the redisson library which didnt help much.

Need to even consider the failover cases whenever a instance is down.Please help.

Thanks

Comment: You can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288810/spring-scheduled-task-running-in-clustered-environment/35911772

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/shedlock-spring)

Include in your pom.xml schedlock dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
    <artifactId>shedlock-spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
    <artifactId>shedlock-provider-jdbc-template</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Create `shedlock` table

```
CREATE TABLE shedlock(
  name VARCHAR(64),
  lock_until TIMESTAMP(3) NULL,
  locked_at TIMESTAMP(3) NULL,
  locked_by  VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (name)
)
```

And don't forget to add a name to each job you create.

```
@SchedulerLock(name = "job_name")
```

This way, when this job will be executed on multiple instances, job record will be added to `shedlock` table by the first instance, and all other instances will check `shedlock` table for existing records with needed job name. This way the job will be executed only once.

Comment: thanks for the solution. Tested the changes and it works fine. :)