# How to run scheduler in multiple instances without collision - Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there any way to handle spring boot scheduler service to run in multiple nodes. If we keep running on single node it will require more time to process the operation. How to increase the performance when we running on same scheduler in multiple nodes(data source will be same table). In this scenario how we can avoid the data collision?

Is there any better way to handle this kind of requirement?

Comment: you can use any db to store process information and based on state you can pick/drop or perform any operation in distributed manner

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Distribute the work on multiple nodes or make spring scheduling run in a distributed environment? For the later see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288810/spring-scheduled-task-running-in-clustered-environment

Comment: I want to run my scheduler distributed way(multiple nodes) so that my data source can be picked for faster processing